# Cut and labels/breaks length conflict

Tags: r, cut

I am working with the cut function to prep data for a barplot histogram but keep running into a seeming inconsistency between my labels and breaks:

`Error in cut.default(sample(1:1e+05, 500, T), breaks = sq, labels = sprintf("$%.0f",  : 
  labels/breaks length conflict`

Here is an example. I pretend that it is income data, using a sequence of 0 to $100,000 in bins of $10,000. I use the same variable to generate both breaks and labels, with minor formating on the label side. I thought they might for some reason have different lengths when comparing to a character vector, but they appear to have the same length, still.

```
> sq<-seq(0,100000,10000)
> cut(sample(1:100000, 500, T),breaks=sq,labels=sprintf("$%.0f",sq))
> length(sprintf("$%.0f",sq))
[1] [11]
> length(sq)
[1] [11]
```

**EDIT:**

Per @thelatemail and @Josh O'Brien's suggestions, I changed the code to this and things are in working order. 
`cut(sample(1:100000, 500, T),breaks=sq,labels=sprintf("$%.0f",sq[-1]))`

Comment: `length(table(cut(sample(1:100000, 500, T),breaks=sq)))` is `10`, hence your mismatch.

Comment: If the end result is going to be a histogram, why don't you simply use the `breaks` parameter to the `hist()` function?

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. But I was curious as to why I couldn't sort out the `cut` issue all the same.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With `cut()`, 11 breaks delimit 10 levels which will require only 10 labels. The `"labels/breaks length conflict"` error is telling you that the call to `sprintf()` is supplying one too many labels to the `labels=` argument.

In code:

```
breaks <- 0:10/10
dat <- runif(1e4)

length(breaks)
# [1] 11
length(levels(cut(breaks, sq)))
# [1] 10
```

Comment: Nice and clear. Amazingly, the [not-so-clear doc for `cut()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cut.html) doesn't say anywhere *"if `breaks` is a vector, then `labels` must be a vector with length one less than `breaks`"*. I feel a docbug coming on.